# With two tabs open to site, can you tell which tab is active?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, browser

Our intranet site has an unusual set of requirements.

- It functions like a multi-page desktop application.  For a single client, our users will be entering information on up to 30 screens.
- It is an Asp.Net MVC3 based site with all session state disabled for efficient operation on a web farm.
- For privacy reasons, we cannot use the query string to show any client information.  We are currently using cookies to store client identification.
- Our user base wants to have multiple tabs open in one browser (IE, FF or Chrome).

If I assume that the user is only going to be using a single, then I can store the client info in a simple cookie and everything works fine.

When the user opens a second tab, it would reuse the same cookie.  Not the desired condition.  So is it possible to determine the difference between the browser tabs?

Comment: It seems that the assertions made in your requirements indicate a lack of understanding of whoever wrote them.  Why would keeping a unique identifier to client information in the query string compromise privacy?

Comment: It's related to nature of the data.  However, an encrypted key would sound like a good idea.

Comment: I'm thinking a generic unique identifier would be sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `sessionStorage` object to store data specific to a single window/tab. It works just like any other JavaScript object, in that you can assign (`sessionStorage.foo = "bar"`), retrieve (`baz = sessionStorage.foo`) and delete (`delete sessionStorage.foo`), but unlike other JS objects any properties set will be persistent across pageloads in a single window.

The only downside is that it doesn't send this data to the server. You have to do this yourself using an AJAX call.

Answer (score 0):

Look into the `window.name` variable. On page load you can put something unique in it, like the date/time, and store the same thing in your cookie (if its not present). If the user opens a new tab (or window), the value will be empty and the cookie won't be. `window.name` persists across page loads (if memory serves), so this will allow you to uniquely identify each tab.

Comment: `window.name` shouldn't be relied on, especially as there are better-suited solutions now.